# Measuring Frequency of Square wave in MATLAB using USB 1024HLS

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to measure the frequency of a square wave which is read through a USB 1024 HLS Daq module through MATLAB. What I've done is create a loop which reads 100 values from the digitial input and that gives me vector of 0's and 1's. There is also a timer in this loop which measures the duration for which the loop runs.

After getting the vector, I then count the number of 1's and then use frequency = num_transitions/time to give me the frequency. However, this doesn't seem to work well :( I keep getting different frequencies for different number of iterations of the loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you count the number of 1s? Could you provide the code? I'd recommend summing the vector.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest trying the following code:

```
vec = ...(the 100-element vector of digital values)...
dur = ...(the time required to collect the above vector)...
edges = find(diff(vec));  % Finds the indices of transitions between 0 and 1
period = 2*mean(diff(edges));  % Finds the mean period, in number of samples
frequency = 100/(dur*period);
```

First, the code finds the indices of the transitions from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0. Next, the differences between these indices are computed and averaged, giving the average duration (in number of samples) for the lengths of zeroes and ones. Multiplying this number by two then gives the average period (in number of samples) of the square wave. This number is then multiplied by `dur/100` to get the period in whatever the time units of `dur` are (i.e. seconds, milliseconds, etc.). Taking the reciprocal then gives the average frequency.

One additional caveat: in order to get a good estimate of the frequency, you might have to make sure the 100 samples you collect contain at least a few repeated periods.

Functions of interest used above: [DIFF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/diff.html), [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/find.html), [MEAN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/mean.html)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to make sure that your 100 samples contain at least one full period of the signal, otherwise you'll get false results. You need a good compromise of sample rate (i.e. the more samples per period you have the better the measurement is) and and number of samples.

To be really precise, you should either have a timestamp associated with every measurement (as you usually can't be sure that you get equidistant time spacing in the for loop) or perhaps it's possible to switch your USB module in some "running" mode which doesn't only get one sample at a time but a complete waveform with fixed samplerate.

Concerning the calculation of the frequency, gnovice already pointed out the right way. If you have individual timestamps (in seconds), the following changes are necessary:

```
tst = ...(the timestamps associated with every sample)...
period = 2*mean(diff(tst(edges)));
frequency = 1/period;
```

Comment: +1: Good point about the individual timestamps. It's hard to tell from the question which way exactly they are measuring time (either for each sample or for all 100 samples).

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out the problem, but if the boolean vector were **v** then,

```
frequency = sum(v)/time_to_give_me_the_frequency
```

Comment: I don't think this would work correctly, unless you are certain that the vector contains *only* one full period. For example, the above code would compute the same frequency for these two vectors: v = [1 0 1 0 1 0]; v = [1 1 1 0 0 0];

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it doesn't sound like a problem with the software, UNLESS you are using the Windows system timer, which is notoriously inaccurate (it is only accurate to about 15 milliseconds).

There are high-resolution timers available in Windows, but I don't know how to use them in Matlab.  If you have access to the .NET framework, the [Stopwatch class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) has 1 microsecond accuracy (or better), as does the [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904(VS.85).aspx) API in Win32.

Other than that, you might have some jitter.  There could be something in your signal chain that is causing false triggers, etc.

**UPDATE:**  The following CodeProject article should solve the timing problem, if there is one.  You should check the Matlab documentation of your version of Matlab to see if it has a native high-resolution timer.  Otherwise, you can use this:

**C++/Mex wrapper adds microsecond resolution timer to Matlab under WinXP**
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/Matlab_Microsecond_Timer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

mersenne31:

Thanks everyone for your responses. I have tried the solutions that gnovice and groovingandi mentioned and I'm sure they will work as soon as the timing issue is solved.

The code I've used is shown below:

for i=1:100 tic; value = getvalue(portCH); vector(i) = value(1); tst(i) = toc; % gets an individual time sample end

% to get the total time I put total_time = toc after the for loop

totaltime = sum(tst); edges = find(diff(vec)); % Finds the indices of transitions between 0 and 1 period = 2*mean(diff(edges)); % Finds the mean period, in number of samples frequency = 100/(totaltime*period);

The problem is that measuring the time for one sample doesn't really help because it is nearly the same for all samples. What is needed is, as groovingandi mentioned, some "running" mode which reads 100 samples for 3 seconds.

So something like for(3 seconds) and then we do the data capture. But I can't find anything like this. Is there any function in MATLAB that could do this?

Answer (score 0):

This won't answer your question, but it's what I thought of after reading you question.  square waves have infinite frequency.  The FFT of a square wave it sin(x)/x, which goes from -inf to +inf.

Also try counting only the rising edges in matlab.  You can quantize the signal to just +1 and 0, and then only increment the count when you see [0 1] slice of your vector.

OR

You can quantize, decimate, then just sum.  This will only work if the each square pulse is the same length and your sampling frequency is constant.  I think this one would be harder to do.